# run gazebo simulation without graphics output

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm not interested in graphics output so I would know if it is possible to run a simulation without displaying the output in order to speed up simulation.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33610/run-gazebo-simulation-without-graphics-output/) by [forsand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2122/forsand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run gazebo headless with argument -r ( Check [there](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/RunningSimulatorHeadless) for detailed informations )

However have a look on this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33418/gazebo-node-arguments-list) about some issues with -r options.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3